# What is the difference between this() and new Object() inside a overloaded constructor?

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

I have the following code:

```
public Account() { #1
    id = 0;
    balance = 0;
    interestRate = 4.5;
}

public Account(int newId, double newBalance) {
    //this(); - option 1
    //new Account(); - - option 2
    id = newId;
    balance = newBalance;
}

public Account(int newId) { #2
    new Account();
    id = novoId;
}
```

When creating an Object with `Account account = new Account(int);` it runs through #2 to #1 to #2.

The question is that option 1 and option 2 seem to render the same behavior (looking through debugger) which seems a bit counter-intuitive. Can somebody shed some light on it?

Comment: These two examples should not act the same. Creating a new Account inside the constructor for Account will start a recursive creation until the stack runs out.

Comment: @NomadMaker in this case, there will be no recursive creation of `Account` instances because `new Account();` will invoke the no-argument constructor and inside that constructor there's no constructor call.

Comment: @Yousaf What about ``new Account()``?

Comment: @NomadMaker what about it? OP created in instance using `new Account(int);`, so `new Account()` will only be called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is very important: `this()` will chain the creation/initialization of the current object to the no-argument constructor `Account()`, while `new Account()` will create **a second** object of type `Account` using the no-argument constructor `Account()`, and then immediately throw it away.

For example, with:

```
public Account(int newId) {
    new Account();
    id = novoId;
}
```

Calling, `new Account(5)`, will do

1. Create object#1 of type Account
2. Call constructor Account(int) with 5 for object#1
3. **Create object#2 of type Account**
4. Call constructor Account() for **object#2**
5. Set id=0, balance=0, interestRate=4.5 for **object#2**
6. (end constructor of step 4)
7. (return to constructor of step 2)
8. Set id=5 for object#1
9. (end constructor call of step 2)

End result: created object has id=5, balance=0 (default), interestRate=0 (default)

With

```
public Account(int newId) {
    this();
    id = novoId;
}
```

Calling, `new Account(5)`, will do

1. Create object#1 of type Account
2. Call constructor Account(int) with 5 for object#1
3. Call constructor Account() for object#1
4. Set id=0, balance=0, interestRate=4.5 for object#1
5. (end constructor of step 3)
6. (return to constructor of step 2)
7. Set id=5 for object#1
8. (end constructor call of step 2)

End result: created object has id=5, balance=0, interestRate=4.5

So, an important difference is that when you use `this()` in your constructor, the `interestRate` of the object you created with `new Account(int)` or `new Account(int, double)` will have been initialized to 4.5, but when using `new Account()` in your constructor, it will be 0 (assuming you don't have an initialization in the declaration itself).

Personally, I would recommend changing your constructors to :

```
public Account(int newId, double newBalance) {
    id = newId;
    balance = newBalance;
    interestRate = 4.5;
}

public Account() {
    this(0, 0);
}

public Account(int newId) {
    this(newId, 0);
}
```

That is - in my opinion - more clear, and establish a clear order of initialization.

Comment: That was what I was thinking. The confusion grew from static initialization of interestRate in the other part of the code.
Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: @IgorKolesnikov That is not static initialization, that is just initialization. Static initialization concerns use of `static { ... }` or direct initialization of static fields. This is also why it is important to post a [mre] when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, your intent seems to be that when you create an instance of `Account` class

```
Account account = new Account(int);
```

you want to initialize the instance using the no-argument constructor in `Account` class and the correct way to do it is using the first option, i.e. `this()`.

Reason why first option is correct way to do what you want is because

```
this();
```

this will invoke the no-argument constructor to continue the initialization of the newly created instance but

```
new Account();
```

will create a new instance of `Account` class which will obviously lead to invocation of the no-argument constructor which is probably not what you want.

So, first option will invoke the no-argument constructor to initialize the newly created instance of `Account` class whereas the second option will create a new instance of `Account` class that will be completely different from the instance that lead to the invocation of the constructor in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods call the default constructor.

- Using "this()" you are calling the constructor of the current instance
- with "new Account()" you are creating a new instance by calling its default constructor.

The first option is correct, because I suppose you want to set all the variables of the current instance.